# Reading a huge edgelist and plot it in NetworkX

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have a huge edgelist named `Reed98.edgelist`. I'm using networkx to read and plot it as graph. This error appears:

```
C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\networkx-1.7-py2.6.egg\networkx\drawing\layout.py:369: DeprecationWarning: functions overriding warnings.showwarning() must support the 'line' argument
  pos+=(displacement*t/length).T
C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\networkx-1.7-py2.6.egg\networkx\drawing\layout.py:514: DeprecationWarning: functions overriding warnings.showwarning() must support the 'line' argument
  pos[:,i]*=scale/lim
```

My code:

```
import networkx as nx
import pylab as plt

G=nx.read_edgelist('Reed98.edgelist')
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

With a sample edgelist like:

```
0   2
0   3
0   5
0   9
0   602
0   11
1   443
1   445
1   456
1   463
1   478
2   134
2   136
2   9
2   10
.......
.......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These must be something else wrong with the file "Reed98.edgelist", or with the installation of `networkx`. I would verify that simple graphs work as intended first. When I try your *exactly* as above with your sample dataset, I get a working graph:

[image]

Comment: @ Hooked, I also get the output for these edgelist. But if I increase this list into huge numbers that error appear. Thanks for your responses.